# Using jQuery to add paragraph tags and skip HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some HTML being fed in to me for blogs and want to be able to ensure it's parsed properly.

I am using this jQuery function (below) to ensure text is being wrapped in a paragraph tag however it seems to be filtering out the `strong` and `a` tags into their own paragraph tags.

Here is the original HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
  <h2>This is a title</h2>
  This is content that will need to be wrapped in a paragraph tag <strong>and this is bold</strong> and this is a <a href="">link</a>.<br />
  More content here.
</div>
```

Now using this function to filter this:

```
$('#demo')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.textContent).length;
  })
  .wrap('</p>');
```

Renders me this HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
  <h2>This is a title</h2>
  <p>This is content that will need to be wrapped in a paragraph tag </p>
  <strong>and this is bold</strong>
  <p> and this is a </p>
  <a href="">link</a>.
  <p>More content here.</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm getting half of what I need but it's separating the HTML elements outside of the paragraph tag. Is there a way I can allow these HTML elements to remain inside the paragraph tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `h2` element, remove it from the structure, wrap what remains and add back in the `h2`.

```js
let cloned = $("#demo > h2").clone(); // Clone the <h2>
$("#demo > h2").remove();             // Remove the <h2>
$("#demo").wrapInner("<p>");          // Wrap everyting left over
cloned.insertBefore("p");             // Put <h2> back

console.log($("#demo").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h2>This is a title</h2>
  This is content that will need to be wrapped in a paragraph tag <strong>and this is bold</strong> and this is a <a href="">link</a>.
  More content here.
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm this is close but I actually forgot to add the <br /> tag in to separate the two text lines, and to have the intetion of having two paragraph tags rather than one big one. Thanks for your answer though!